# Is there an equivalent to the rewind function, but for one token only?

Tags: c, loops, token

In the C language, the rewind function is used to set the position of a stream to the very beginning. I'd like to ask if there's an equivalent function that moves the stream position to the left by one token only.

For example, I have a file called FooFile.txt that contains several lines of sequences of integers separated by a " " whitespace character.

```
int main()
{
    // open file stream.
    FILE *FooFile = fopen("FooFile.txt" , "r");
    int Bar = 0;

    // loop through every integer token in the file stream.
    while ( fscanf( FooFile, "%d", &Bar ) == 0 )
    {
        // I don't want to reset the stream to the very beginning.
        // rewind( FooFile );
        // I only need to move the stream back one token.

        Bar = fscanf ( FooFile, "%d", &Bar )
        Bar = fscanf ( FooFile, "%d", &Bar )
    }
}
```

Comment: See `fgetpos` and `fsetpos`.  Best of luck.

Comment: For 1 character cases, `ungetc()` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `"%n"` specifier to know how many characters were read, and then you `fseek()` the negative number of characters read, this is an example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * file  = fopen("FooFile.txt" , "r");
    int    bar   = 0;
    int    count = 0;

    if (file == NULL)
        return -1;

    while (fscanf(file, "%d%n", &bar, &count) == 1)
    {
        fseek(file, -count, SEEK_CUR);
        /* if you don't re-scan the value, the loop will be infinite */
        fscanf(file, "%d", &bar);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Please note**, that in your code there is an error, `fscanf()` does not return the read value, but the number of arguments matched by the specifiers.

Comment: This method may fail, especially if newlines precede the number. Performing an `fseek()` on a text file is UB unless that destination is the result of a previous `ftell()` or is an effective rewind, or goto end.  C11dr  §7.21.9.2  "For a text stream, either offset shall be zero, or offset shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the ftell function on a stream associated with the same file and whence shall be SEEK_SET."  Suggest re-thinking this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ftell` for getting the current position and `fseek` for setting the current position, if a `long` is big enough.

Better use `fgetpos` and `fsetpos` for the full range of possible file-offsets though.

```
#include <stdio.h>

fpos_t pos;
if(fgetpos(file, &pos)) abort(); // Get position

/* do naughty things */

fsetpos(file, pos); // Reset position
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fsetpos

Comment: Nice: Performing an `ftell()` or `fgetpos()` is the best way to set-up to re-position the file pointer in a text file.